# How can I access to method parameter's own type data in specific class using Roslyn API(C# Code Analysis)

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, rules

I'm developing my own custom rules using **Roslyn API(C# Code Analysis)**.

I want to get method parameter's own type class inheritance information in specific namespace's name.

First, I initialized `RegisterSyntaxNodeAction` to `SyntaxKind.CompilationUnit` in `DiagnosticAnalyzer class's Initialize method`.

Second, I accessed specific namespace's name(`ex:BIZprj`).

Third, I got the parameter's type instance(`ex:parameterType`)

Until here, I tried to serveral times to get parameter type instance's inheritance name. **How can I resolve this?**

**my code example**

```
public class SampleAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
{

//...
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
            context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeNode, SyntaxKind.CompilationUnit);
}

private void AnalyzeNode(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
{
            var rootNode = (CompilationUnitSyntax)context.Node;
            ... go to MethodNode
    var methodParameters = methodNode.ParameterList.Parameters;
    foreach(var param in methodParameters)
    {
        var parameterType = param.Type;
        // **Here is what I want to get parameter type's inheritance class name.!!**
    }
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev66K.png)

Comment: I understand you have trouble with getting the inheritance details of a method parameter, but you are able to get the actual method parameter type. Now challenge with hierarchy is to what level would you like to go, is it immediate level or all the way to the top object base class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code, where I have documented various parts, we are essentially going to the `MethodNode`, traversing further to the `ParameterSyntax` collection and for each `parameter` first node is `Type` and Last is the `parameter name`, once we have the type of any parameter, we can also get the `Base type` and from that you can fetch the Type Name as shown in the image

```
// Fetch the CompilationUnitSyntax
var rootNode = (CompilationUnitSyntax)context.Node;

// Filter out the collection of MethodDeclarationSyntax
var methodSyntaxNodes = from methodDeclaration 
                        in rootNode.DescendantNodes().Where(x => x is MethodDeclarationSyntax )
                        select methodDeclaration;

// Traverse through each MethodNode                             
foreach(var methodNode in methodSyntaxNodes)
{
    var mNode = (MethodDeclarationSyntax)methodNode;

    // Traverse through each Parameter Syntax       
    foreach(var parameterSytanx in mNode.ParameterList.Parameters)
    {
        // Get First Token and Fetch the BaseType
        var baseType = parameterSytanx.GetFirstToken().GetType().BaseType;
    }           
}
```

Comment: Welcome, keep me posted if this doesn't help and you need something different